# Nested Droppable And Sortable With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have two divs (firstList, secondList) which have bootstrap panel items in them.

I can drag and drop bootstrap panel item from firstList to secondList and viceversa.

Both lists are sortable.

I can handle this.  However I want to make some panel items droppable also.

Here is some code:

```
//draggable panel items.  
$(".block").draggable({ 
      addClasses: false,
      connectToSortable: "#secondList, #firstList, .droppableBlock",
      revert: true,
      revertDuration: 0,
      zIndex: 1000,
    });
//droppable panel items.
    $(".droppableBlock").droppable({
        accept: "*", 
        greedy: true,
        drop : function(event, ui){
          ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));
        }      
    });

//lists are sortable and droppable
    $("#secondList, #firstList").sortable({
      items: ".block",    
    }).droppable({
        greedy: false,
        drop : function(event, ui){                
            $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
            ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));         
      }    
    });
});
```

Some Html Elements

```
<!-- Sample block element. I can drag and drop it. -->
   <div class="panel panel-default " id="uniq2">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Drop Here</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body droppableBlock">
        <!-- I want to drop .block elements to here. -->
      </div>
             <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title ">Drop Here </h3>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body droppableBlock">
        <!-- I want to drop .block elements to here. -->
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Default Block Element -->
    <div class="panel panel-default block" id="uniq1">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anything 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Sample https://jsfiddle.net/LmeLfv81/

When i remove

```
  connectToSortable: "#secondList, #firstList, .droppableBlock",
```

this line. I can drag and drop .block items to .droppableBlock. But that time i can not sort items. When i add connectToSortable i can sort. But i can not drag and drop .block items to .droppableBlock.

Comment: I ended up using this to solve your problem: https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/